# Why does Blender save my work how it wants?

Tags: saving

I have 12x6 meshes that are put together in another program.

I dont want AUTO-GENERATED sharp edges... so I "clear sharp" - save - and reload the model just to discover that the sharp edges are back again.

How are you supposed to work efficiently when you can't even be sure your work is being saved correctly?

Comment: No one can answer that as written. What other program is involved? Do you have a screenshot or blend file for others to see or repeat the problem on their own? "reload the model" do you mean you don't open the saved file but instead import the potential problem again?

Comment: Of course people can.
The other program is irrelevant.
I just want the model not to have any sharp edges. I clear all sharp edges, save it as an obj.
The problem is, that you'd expect the sharp edges to be gone, don't you? I REMOVED them and SAVED the model.
But then I import the SAVED model with SUPPOSEDLY no sharp edges into blender to test it - and there they are: all sharp edges as if I didn't remove them.

I know this is a so called "user error" - But why are the default (save) setting so incredibly bad and hidden away?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you are importing an .obj, saving a .blend, then reimporting the .obj file again? If so, that doesn't have anything to do with hidden save settings, it is standard practice in all professional software (that I am aware of) that saving and exporting are two very different actions.

Comment: What? NO!
I'm not 4 years old - I import the newly saved model and see that my changes did NOT get saved. Read my first reply... slowly. Everything is described in detail in few sentences.

And to be perfectly clear (although this is irrelevant if you understand the question) I created the model from scratch in blender in the first place so the first loadable version is the first save onto the harddrive...

Comment: There isn't enough information to help you yet. Please provide a screenshot or blend file. You said you have one for others to see; let's have a look!

Comment: There is enough information, I'm writing an answer.

Comment: So when you 'Save', you are actually performing an 'Export' so that the file you just edited is exported as an .obj, do I have that right now? Apologies for what is probably a frustrating line of questioning, but I find that using consistent language to describe operations taken within a program (especially a complicated one like Blender) can help a great deal in finding a common solution.

Comment: I do not know how to post images here. All you'd see is a model with sharp edges and the same one without sharp edges (same vert count!!! - I do not select and delete edges, i *clear* them). I save the second and import it, then I'd be at image 1 again; clear => image 2, save, lod => image 1; clear => image 2 save, load => image 1 infinite loop.

Comment: I agree Onyz - I am a math student. Clarity of of expression is often undervalued.

I just assumed you were ...assuming that I exported the model (as an .obj in this case), because I mentioned save settings, which isn't relevant in regard to .blend files, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, my assumption occurred earlier in the reading process and wound up totally giving me the wrong idea of what was going on here. It seems like we have a conclusive answer either way now, so I suppose things worked out regardless.

Answer (score 7):

The mark sharp feature only exists within Blender, it's not part of the [.obj specification](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/). The format has two ways to describe the normals of the model, vertex normals (`vn`) and smoothing groups (`s`). When you're exporting a model with only flat shading applied then the resulting file will have smoothing groups disabled and a normal for each face in the model.

The exported model in .obj format will be exactly the same, no matter if you applied flat shading to the entire model or marked every edge as sharp.

Blender's obj importer checks whether or not smoothing groups are used and it will mark all edges at the boundary between smoothing groups as sharp or every edge, if no smoothing groups are used at all. In your case it's the latter. Therefore Blender exports the file correctly, however the implementation of the importer always uses the *mark sharp* feature even when the entire model is flat shaded.

If you want to retain Blender specific properties, then you will have to save the model as .blend file (*File > Save*). The .obj format is quite limited in what information can be stored and therefore it cannot preserve all features available in Blender.

If you want to export a model to .obj with smooth shading the solution is to perform two steps:

1. Select all faces in edit mode and use *Edge > Clear Sharp* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
2. Set shading to smooth in object mode *Object > Shade Smooth*

The exported model will now use smooth shading and will also be re-imported with smooth shading.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification in regards to the backend of blender.

The *reason* as to why I do not want sharp edges is that the individual models are combined seamlessly in another program.
This works fine because the verts are alligned perfectly, but there is a visible "seam" that is cause by different shading (usually way darker than surrounding faces) of faces that have "sharp edges" - at least that's the only reason I could come up with, since the shading stays the same when a model is not "connected" to other meshes.

So the data is being saved, the blender importer just... well...

Comment: @47Mortuus In that case you should merge the objects properly by eliminating duplicate vertices and internal faces. Sounds like you might have issues with inverted normals or normal interpolation due to improper combination of models. It would make sense to post a separate question for this. Also it's a good idea to always state the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because then we can suggest an approach that's suitable.

Comment: @47Mortuus If this answered your question, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.